# How can I write a regular expression to check if the 2 properties in an asp.net control have the same name?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have the following asp.net custom validator:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" 
ClientValidationFunction="valUCRRequired" ID="valUCRRequired"
ErrorMessage="Field 7-Date/Time Between is Required"
ControlToValidate="DTE_FROM" />
```

Notice that the `ID` and `ClientValidationFunction` have the same value.  I want to do a regular expression search where they are the same.  Right now, I am just searching for all CustomValidators.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex and do a regex search for:

```
ClientValidationFunction="([^"]*)" ID="\1"
```

The parentheses capture the value to Group 1. The `\1` is a back-reference to Group 1. Therefore the regex only matches if the two values are the same.

**EDIT**

You mention you are having trouble making it match in VS2013. It works for me (see screenshot).

[image]

Comment: I tried this in vs 2013 and when I select regex as a search option, it says it can't find the following text:  `ClientValidationFunction="([^"]*)" ID="\1"`

Comment: @xaisoft Strange, it works for me (see screenshot). Some editors and languages use `$1` instead of `\1` for backreferences, or `${1}` or `\{1}` but as you can see on the screenshot VS2013 is behaving as in the solution.

Comment: Weird, I did exactly what you are doing and I am 100% positive there are matches,but it keeps telling me that it can't find the text.

Comment: @xaisoft There are so many editions of VS (pro etc), wondering if that could be it? The regex is correct, so... as a workaround, can I suggest you try it in Notepad++ (free) or EditPadPro if you have it (not free but great regex support)